# creating a sub-query

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Sub-Query Help

I'm having a problem creating a sub-query (I think) and was hoping to get some guidance. Some things have been generalized for simplicity.

```
Select
A
b
c
d
e
Member ID
Hospital Admit Date
DRG Code
CLM_LN_SVC_FROM_DT

From
Claims Table

Where
DRG Code = 5
And A
And B
And c
```

I would like to take the result of this query specifically the Member ID and distinct Hospital Admit Dates for the Member and query against the claims table for all claims:
where Member ID in (result from above query) and at this point I need to pull claims in the range 30 days before the admit dates and up to 180 days after the admit date.  This is where I'm struggling how to setup this sub query.  Any brilliance beyond my limited base would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Can you please specify which tables are involved and what primary key/foreign key they have? From what you write it is only clear that there is a Claims table. It also seems there is a Member table from where you could retrieve Member ID and Hospital Admit Date.

Comment: With respect to this query, it is only the Claims Table.  There is no join at this time.  Ultimately this will be used as part of a query set for a carve out.  Essentially what I'm trying to do is run a query take a few results of that query key where DRG = 5 (Member ID, Claim Date, Admitted Date) and then use these results as parameters in a query against all of the claims (match member id, and pull all claims -30 & +180 of the admit date.  What I'm trying to isolate is where a certain procedure takes place and admission and all of the claims activity within a range that may or not be related

Comment: Too much description, too few examples. Honestly, a good illustration of the problem goes a long way. A data sample and the expected result for it would probably be good enough (a good start at the very least).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds you need something similar to following query:

```
Select Distinct
       ClaPeriod.MemberId,
       ClaPeriod.DRGCode,
       ClaPeriod.ClaimDate,
       ClaPeriod.AdmittedDate,
       A,
       B,
       C,
       D,
       E
  From Claims ClaMain,
       Claims ClaPeriod
 Where (ClaMain.MemberId, ClaMain.AdmittedDate) In (
                                                      Select MemberId, AdmittedDate
                                                        From Claims claId
                                                       Where DRGCode = 5
                                                   )
   And ClaMain.MemberId = ClaPeriod.MemberId
   And ClaPeriod.AdmittedDate >= ClaMain.AdmittedDate - 30 
   And ClaPeriod.DischargedDate <= ClaMain.AdmittedDate + 180                   
 Order By ClaPeriod.MemberId, ClaPeriod.AdmittedDate
```

To be honest, I still am not sure I have fully understood your schema. I had to include a `Distinct` clause in my sql test to avoid duplicate results. If I missed the mark please tell me so and I will try to improve the answer.

---

**UPDATE**: Now that the schema is clearer for me as per OP's comments I will try to improve the answer.

As I understand it now, you need to get all claims that:

- have the same MBR_ID as a claim with DRG=5.
- have an HOSP_ADMT_DT (Admit Date) 30 days prior or before than the CLM_LN_SVC_FROM_DT (From_Date) of the DRG=5 claim.
- have an HOSP_DSCHRG_DT (Discharge Date) at least 180 days after the CLM_LN_SVC_FROM_DT (From_Date) of the DRG=5 claim.

If it is so, it can be done with a query that joins the `CLM_MED_DETL` to itself. ne table would be to filter the claims with DRG=5 and the other to retrieve the claims that have the same MBR_ID and that comply with the date conditions. It would be a query like following:

```
  Select CLAIMS.CLM_MED_DETL_ID,
         CLAIMS.CLM_LN_CURR_STAT_TXT,
         CLAIMS.CLM_ID_TXT,
         CLAIMS.SVCG_PROV_NAME,
         CLAIMS.SBMTD_DRG_CD,
         CLAIMS.RVNU_CD,
         CLAIMS.PLC_OF_SVC_CD,
         CLAIMS.CLM_SRC_CD,
         CLAIMS.CLM_LN_SEQ_NUM,
         CLAIMS.CLM_LN_PRCDR_CD,
         CLAIMS.MBR_ID,
         CLAIMS.MBR_LST_NAME,
         CLAIMS.MBR_FST_NAME,
         CLAIMS.SVCG_PROV_ADDR_ZIP_CD,
         CLAIMS.SVCG_PROV_ADDR_CNTY,
         CLAIMS.HOSP_ADMT_DT,
         CLAIMS.HOSP_DSCHRG_DT,
         CLAIMS.CLM_LN_UNITS_NUM,
         CLAIMS.CLM_LN_CHRG_AMT,
         CLAIMS.CLM_LN_ALWD_AMT,
         CLAIMS.CLM_LN_PD_AMT,
         CLAIMS.TIN_TXT,
         CLAIMS.CLM_LN_SVC_FROM_DT,
         CLAIMS.CLM_LN_SVC_TO_DT
    From CLM_MED_DETL DRG5CLAIMS,
         CLM_MED_DETL CLAIMS    
   Where CLAIMS.MBR_ID = DRG5CLAIMS.MBR_ID
     And DRG5CLAIMS.SBMTD_DRG_CD = '005'
     And DRG5CLAIMS.CLM_LN_SVC_FROM_DT >= CLAIMS.HOSP_ADMT_DT - 30
     And DRG5CLAIMS.CLM_LN_SVC_FROM_DT <= CLAIMS.HOSP_DSCHRG_DT + 180
     And CLAIMS.CLM_SRC_CD = 'TRG_FA'
     And CLAIMS.CLM_LN_PD_AMT <> 0
     And CLAIMS.CLM_LN_CURR_STAT_TXT <> 91
Order By CLAIMS.MBR_LST_NAME Asc, CLAIMS.CLM_LN_SEQ_NUM Asc;
```

Comment: Hi Guillem,  Thank you for your response!!!  This all occurs in one table.  I'm trying to identify all the members with DRG 5 and then take those member ID's and admit dates (say 1,000 records) and query the claims table again (millions of records) and pull all of those members claims for admit - 30 and plus 180 in which is CLM_LN_SVC_From.  So 2nd part of query removes drg 5 and takes member id's and admit dates where drg was 5 and then queries again with drg 5 and condition admit -30 +180 is used as a parameter on CLM_LN_SVC_From.  Not quite sure how to do this...

Comment: I thought the input might look something like:

Comment: Select CLM_MED_DETL_ID, CLM_LN_CURR_STAT_TXT, CLM_ID_TXT, SVCG_PROV_NAME, SBMTD_DRG_CD, CLM_LN_SEQ_NUM, CLM_LN_PRCDR_CD, MBR_ID, SVCG_PROV_ADDR_ZIP_CD, HOSP_ADMT_DT, HOSP_DSCHRG_DT, CLM_LN_PD_AMT, CLM_LN_SVC_FROM_DT, CLM_LN_SVC_TO_DT
    From CLM_MED_DETL
    Where MBR_ID In (Select MBR_ID
    From CLM_MED_DETL
    Where SBMTD_DRG_CD = '005')
    and CLM_LN_SVC_FROM_DT >= HOSP_ADMT_DT - 30
    and CLM_LN_SVC_FROM_DT <= HOSP_DSCHRG_DT + 180)
    and CLM_SRC_CD = 'TRG_FA' 
    and CLM_LN_PD_AMT <> 0
    and CLM_LN_CURR_STAT_TXT <> 91
    Order by MBR_LST_NAME ASC, CLM_LN_SEQ_NUM ASC;

Comment: I think it needs an additional subquery.  I want to pull all claims for those members who have a drg 5, which I want the claims 30 days before admit date for DRG 5 and then 180 days after discharge date for DRG 5.  So all claims within that range where inclusion is determined, but not defined by DRG 5.

Comment: I have changed the SQL query to tak in account the `discharge date` (using pseudocode). Please tell me if it is what you need, or at least if it is nearer to it.

Comment: Guillem Vicens,  How do you have two tables? Select CLM_MED_DETL_ID, CLM_LN_CURR_STAT_TXT, CLM_ID_TXT, SVCG_PROV_NAME, SBMTD_DRG_CD, RVNU_CD, PLC_OF_SVC_CD, CLM_SRC_CD, CLM_LN_SEQ_NUM, CLM_LN_PRCDR_CD, MBR_ID, MBR_LST_NAME, MBR_FST_NAME, SVCG_PROV_ADDR_ZIP_CD, SVCG_PROV_ADDR_CNTY, HOSP_ADMT_DT, HOSP_DSCHRG_DT, CLM_LN_UNITS_NUM, CLM_LN_CHRG_AMT, CLM_LN_ALWD_AMT, CLM_LN_PD_AMT, TIN_TXT, CLM_LN_SVC_FROM_DT, CLM_LN_SVC_TO_DT
From CLM_MED_DETL
Where MBR_ID In (Select MBR_ID
From CLM_MED_DETL
Where SBMTD_DRG_CD = '005'

Comment: and CLM_LN_SVC_FROM_DT >= HOSP_ADMT_DT - 30
and CLM_LN_SVC_FROM_DT <= HOSP_DSCHRG_DT + 180)
and CLM_SRC_CD = 'TRG_FA' 
and CLM_LN_PD_AMT <> 0
and CLM_LN_CURR_STAT_TXT <> 91
Order by MBR_LST_NAME ASC, CLM_LN_SEQ_NUM ASC;

Comment: This is close, but not quite there. I don't know if I need two sub queries?

Comment: Your subquery takes all rows from the table where the `MBR_ID` has  DRG=5 and `CLM_LN_SVC_FROM_DT between admittance date - 30 and discharge date + 180. But the subquery gives you **only** the `MBR_ID`. The `main query` is filtering only by MBR_ID and not taking in account the dates. As per the second table, as I told you I was not sure I had understood your schema :-). I will rewrite the query using your schema definition.